# Spark Submit Error Could Not Allocate Memory but Exit Code 0

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I use Spark to do ETL and "could not allocate memory" error occasionaly appears.

The problem here is it returns exit code 0 even when it is failed.

I am using Airflow BashOperator and it uses bash exit code as success parameter. It makes job with mentioned error has false success.

Error log looks like below.

```
[2016-06-22 10:00:54,494] {models.py:974} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitPythonOperator): ingest_track> on 2016-02-12 01:00:00
[2016-06-22 10:00:54,548] {bash_operator.py:52} INFO - tmp dir root location: 
/tmp
[2016-06-22 10:00:54,548] {bash_operator.py:61} INFO - Temporary script location :/tmp/airflowtmp7gl4hl//tmp/airflowtmp7gl4hl/ingest_track0lEaKC
[2016-06-22 10:00:54,548] {bash_operator.py:62} INFO - Running command: spark-submit.sh --master yarn-cluster --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1 --num-executors 1 ingest_script.py --dt "2016-02-12 01:00:00" --env prod --task_id ingest_track
[2016-06-22 10:00:54,556] {bash_operator.py:70} INFO - Output:
[2016-06-22 10:00:55,200] {bash_operator.py:74} INFO - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000771b00000, 82313216, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
[2016-06-22 10:00:55,226] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
```

My question is, **why the exit code is 0 while the submit processes itself failed? How to make it right?**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue but with a different command/process.

Comment: nope we haven't figured it out  yet unfortunately. we make a wrapper that check the error message first before returning another exit code based on the error log